# Angular Add class to ng-repeat element that is updated or added only

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am trying to dynamically add a class to an element that is updated on the view.

http://jsfiddle.net/9s1rfwa8/7/

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" class="bigfont todo done-{{todo.done}}"> <span>{{todo.text}}</span>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
$scope.todos = [{
    text: 'learn angular',
    done: true
}, {
    text: 'build a demo angular appsdfsdfsf',
    done: false
}, {
    text: 'build an awesome angular app',
    done: false
}];
```

}

How do I add a class to the ng-repeat element that is only changed and not to others.

I am trying to give it a flip effect to the elements that changes.

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Ng-repeat will duplicate element that is repeated. If you want to apply class to only one of the element repeated, then you need to add a condition e.g. $index === 0 to ng-class.

```
ng-class={'first-item-class': $index === 0}
```

this will apply to the first element only. Use any kind of condition logic to identify its the one you want to apply to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom filter for this, custom filter will be executed whenever there is a change.

For example you can change done property inside your todo object every time user clicks on the row and use the value of todo.done to set class inside your filter

html

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter:handleChange"
    class="bigfont todo done-{{todo.done}} {{todo.class}}"
    ng-click="todo.done = !todo.done"> 
    <span>{{todo.text}}</span>{{todo.class}}
</li>
```

js

```
$scope.handleChange = function(row){
    if(!row.done){
      row.class = '';
    }
    else{
      row.class = 'changed'
    }

    return true;
}
```

this should give you a general idea on how to approach your problem, you can find a working sample in the following plunker.

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/TIwJmHgxmDFtd3zwcCyd?p=preview)**

Comment: thx for this I understand your code, but can you tell me how i can detect change without the click, my data (number) changes on the model which is fed from a json.  I need solution that detects only the row is changed.

Comment: You can use ng-change, watchers, ... it is hard to tell with the current information that you have provided. If you update your question with relevant code I can help you better.